# Why Does the Algebraic Function $y = \frac {1}{4c}x^2$ Form a Parabola?

Tags: conic-sections

so right now I am taking Algebra 2, and we are learning about Conic Sections. We were of course given the functions to form the shapes of each section (circle, ellipse, parabola, hyperbola). I was just wondering why do these functions form these shapes when graphed? My teacher just gave us the functions, but didn't explain this. Could someone shed some light and/or tell me if this is a useless question? 
(Let me know if you need me to clarify anything, I'm not sure if I explained my question correctly.)

Comment: I believe you either mean $$y^2=4cx$$ or $$x^2=4cy$$?

Comment: Have you learnt the definition of parabola?

Comment: I just learned the definition of a parabola today. Also, I don't know how to enter the equations like that on the forum. The equations you showed aren't what I was trying to enter.

Comment: What is the definition you learnt? (There are a few versions...which are ultimately equivalent)

Comment: MathJax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A parabola is the set of all points in a plane that are the same distance from a fixed line (directrix) and a point not on the line (focus).

Comment: $$ y = \frac {(1)}{4c} x^2$$

Comment: Ok, this is what I was trying to show. Should I edit the title as well?

Comment: I see. See my answer for the explanation. and yep you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the focus on the $x$-axis as $F(c,0)$ and the directrix $x=-c$.

Then from the definition, a point $P(x,y)$ on the parabola satisfies
$$PF=Pd_\perp$$
thus
$$\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-0)^2}=|x-(-c)|$$
Simplifying,
$$y^2=(x+c)^2-(x-c)^2=4cx$$

---

Suppose we have the focus on the $y$-axis as $F(0,c)$ and the directrix $y=-c$.

Then from the definition, a point $P(x,y)$ on the parabola satisfies
$$PF=Pd_\perp$$
thus
$$\sqrt{(y-c)^2+(x-0)^2}=|y-(-c)|$$
Simplifying,
$$x^2=(y+c)^2-(y-c)^2=4cy$$
which gives
$$y=\frac{1}{4c}x^2$$

Comment: Thanks for putting time into this explanation. As I was looking over this and the definition I received in class, this seems like a bit of a silly question :)

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 That's alright haha I was quite confused w conics when I first started learning it also. It's very normal to not be able to link the algebraic and geometric sides of conics together at the start.